# Adding context to a UI control or NSObject

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, nsobject

It's great to be able to `addTarget` on a `UIButton`.  I only wish there was some sneaky way I could attach state to the UIButton so that when the target method is invoked, I could magically pull that state (any id) from the sender.

Something like:

```
[button shoveMyObjectInThere:foo];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchyTouchy:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Followed by:

```
-(void) touchyTouchy:(id) sender {
    UIButton button = (UIButton*)sender;
    id foo = [button getByObjectBack];
    // do something interesting with foo
}
```

Would be great if UIButton had an 'id context' property where developers could shove stuff, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Objective-C is a very dynamic language though, so I wonder if there is some sneaky way I can add method or fields to an object at runtime?

Comment: Wow I LOLed when I saw that selector name!!! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try making an associative reference

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

objc_setAssociatedObject(id object, void *key, id value, objc_AssociationPolicy policy); 
objc_getAssociatedObject(id object, void *key);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like [`setValue:forKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/setValue%3aforKey%3a), a part of the Key-Value coding feature of Objective-C?

Comment: Gave that a whirl and docs and my experimentation seem to indicate that is only for setting existing fields/accessors.

Comment: Doesn't seem possible to add new member data using KVC. See [Why is my object not key value coding-compliant?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11491957/1804403)

Answer (score 0):

So I just did a quick test and found some interesting results.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
[self.window addSubview:button];

// ...

- (void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button clicked %@", [sender class]);
}
```

This prints: `button clicked UIRoundedRectButton`

So it seems like this should be possible... Truth be told, I ran into some problems subclassing `UIButton` to get the full example working but this seems promising. :)

Comment: This answer does not appear to be related to the question. You have not added any context to the UIButton that can be pulled out in `buttonClicked:`

Answer (score 0):

The official solution is to use the "tag" property:

```
[self.someMutableArray addObject:foo];
button.tag = self.someMutableArray.count - 1;

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchyTouchy:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then:

```
-(void) touchyTouchy:(id) sender {
    UIButton button = (UIButton*)sender;
    id foo = self.someMutableArray[button.tag];
    // do something interesting with foo
}
```

In most situations you'd use an `enum` or constant for the tag, but an array is obviously more flexible.