# Why is my object not key value coding-compliant?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-coding

Trying to use key-value coding to set a value on my object:

```
[engine setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:horsePower]
          forKey:@"horsePower"];
```

Causes an error:

```
[<Slant6 0x7fbc61c15c40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key horsePower.
```

What do I need to do to make `engine` key value coding-compliant?

Comment: Now where did I leave my crystal ball...

Comment: Unless you tell us the class of your engine object, there's not too much we can do to help you.

Comment: @ThorstenKarrer although in general it's a good kind of advice for  novices to publish their actual code, here it is *not needed*.

Comment: @H2CO3 depends... if the OP was, for example, trying to call setValue:forKey: on an object of class NSDictionary, a better solution than to add an ivar would have been to change the class to NSMutableDictionary. Also, in this case, the question would have been a duplicate.

Comment: @H2CO3: There could be a number of issues though. `engine` may in fact be KVC-compliant for `horsePower`, but memory management issues may be causing the lookup to be done on the wrong object, etc.

Comment: @dreamlax but in this case we're already talking about another (irrelevant) class.

Comment: @H2CO3: What do you mean? There are no classes mentioned in the entire question, only an instance of something called `engine`.

Comment: #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Engine : NSObject
@end//Engine

Comment: #import "Engine.h"

@implementation Engine
-(NSString *)description
{
    return (@"I am an engine.Vrooom!");
}//description
@end//Engine

Comment: @ThorstenKarrer that's true, but 1. I was kind enough to assume OP knew the awesome site at http://208.117.229.184 2. you're right in the latter, because if it really was a dictionary, adding an ivar is not advisable as it can only be done by subclassing which is discouraged according to Apple.

Comment: thanks for all the people who answer for this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure whatever class `engine` belongs to implements a `horsePower` property, and/or has a `horsePower` instance variable, and/or manually implements `setHorsePower:` and `horsePower` methods.

You are getting the error because you're trying to set the value of the `horsePower` key but `engine`'s class does not properly implement a way to set the `horsePower` key.

Comment: Not necessary, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a [bunch of approaches](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) of taking advantage of KVC - perhaps the simplest is to just have an instance variable in your class with the name of the key you want to use, i. e.:

```
@interface Engine: NSObject {
    NSNumber *horsePower;
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: @FOCUSHUANG no problem, I'm happy to help. Next time please make sure you post some code, it greatly helps others to answer your question.

Comment: You should probably link to the KVC docs which explain all of the ways to make your class KVC-compliant.

Comment: Link to Apple KVC docs: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)